# I creat a custom advancedatagridgroupitemrenderer which using HierarchicalData as dataprovide ,but it does't work

Tags: flex4

I creat a custom advancedatagridgroupitemrenderer which using HierarchicalData as my dataprovide ;

### my itemrenderer like this:

public class XwjsjglAdvancedDgGroupItemRenderer extends AdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer{
        public function XwjsjglAdvancedDgGroupItemRenderer()
        {
            super();
        }

```
    override public function set data(v:Object):void{
        super.data = v;
    }
    protected var img:Image;
    override protected function createChildren():void{
        super.createChildren();
        img= new Image();           
        img.source="/assets/images/indexNow/jsjhc.png";

        this.addChild(DisplayObject(img));      
    }       


    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,
                                                  unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth,unscaledHeight);

        img.x = label.x + 2;
        img.y = label.y + 2;
        label.x = img.x + 70;
    }

    override protected function commitProperties():void
    {
        super.commitProperties();
         }

    override protected function measure():void
    {
        super.measure();
        measuredWidth += 90;
        measuredHeight+= 90;
    }

}
```

and the runing effect is this:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj1B5.png

how can i do ?Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.